# Painting with paintComponent in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a problem with my code.
We have to code a Game called "Mühle" as our project for this semester.

My problem is, that I want to draw my game token on the field and it does not work although the tokens are added to the board and you can click them but they are not visible and I don't know what I can do.

This is the important part frow my GUI Class:

```
public class GUIMühle extends JFrame {
    static JLabel spieler1, spieler2;
    static JFrame frame;
    static JButton[] button;
    static JButton btnReset;
    static int x, y;
    static int gewinner = 0;
    static int player = 2;
    static Buttons[] buttons;
    static Steine[] steine1;
    static Steine[] steine2;

    public GUIMühle(){
        InitUI();
    }

    private void InitUI(){
        MouseEvents ME = new MouseEvents();
        frame = new JFrame("Mühle");

        frame.setSize(960, 540);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        DrawSpielbrett spielbrett = new DrawSpielbrett();
        spielbrett.setBounds(0,0,960,540);
        spielbrett.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(spielbrett);

        spieler1 = new JLabel("Spieler 1");
        spieler1.setBounds(590, 50, 150, 35);
        spieler1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        frame.add(spieler1);

        spieler2 = new JLabel("Spieler 2");
        spieler2.setBounds(785, 50, 150, 35);
        spieler2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        frame.add(spieler2);

        // Spielsteine
        steine1 = Steine.Erstellen(Color.white, 9, 665, 85);
        steine2 = Steine.Erstellen(Color.black, 9, 860, 85);
        DrawSteine[] drawSteine1 = new DrawSteine[9];
        DrawSteine[] drawSteine2 = new DrawSteine[9];
        for(int i = 0; i < steine1.length; i++){
            steine1[i].setBounds(steine1[i].getX(),steine1[i].getY(),30,30);
            steine1[i].addMouseListener(ME);
            steine1[i].setVisible(true);
            frame.add(steine1[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < steine2.length; i++){
            steine2[i].setBounds(860,85+(i*32),30,30);
            steine2[i].addMouseListener(ME);
            frame.add(steine2[i]);
}
```

And this is the part from my game token class:

```
public class Steine extends JLabel{

    private Color farbe;
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Steine(Color farbe, int x, int y){
        this.farbe = farbe;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static Steine[] Erstellen(Color farbe, int anzahl, int x, int y){
        Steine[] steine = new Steine[anzahl];

        for(int i = 0; i < steine.length; i++){

            steine[i] = new Steine(farbe,x,y);
            y = y + 32;
            
        }

        return steine;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(this.farbe);

        g.fillOval(this.x, this.y, 30, 30);

        repaint();
    }

    /*public static void DrawSteine(Steine stein){
        GUIMühle.frame.add(stein);
    }*/

    public Color getFarbe() {
        return this.farbe;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generally, if you're going to draw the game board, you draw the entire game board.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you one way to create a drawing `JPanel`.

Comment: Your title needs translating. English only on this edition of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't invoke repaint() in the paintComponent() method. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Maybe you need a `GridLayout`?

Comment: For more help post [mre]. The code as posted does not compile.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).